# Perfect-scrollbar doesn't apply correctly to a jQuery ui selectmenu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu, perfect-scrollbar

I am trying to add [perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar) plugin (which give a beautiful scrollbar instead of the browser default scrollbar) to a jQuery UI `selectmenu`

This is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mody5/54kjojy3/3/)

When I open the `selectmenu` the scrollbar doesn't show up (even if I hover the list) until I get the mouse near to the bottom of the list (which means : the first time you open the selectmenu it gives a feeling that there are no other items because the scrollbar isn't there)

Any Idea how I can solve that ?

HTML

```
<select name="number" id="number">
      <option>1</option>
      <option selected="selected">2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
      <option>11</option>
      <option>12</option>
      <option>13</option>
      <option>14</option>
      <option>15</option>
      <option>16</option>
      <option>17</option>
      <option>18</option>
      <option>19</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$(function(){    
    $( "#number" ).selectmenu().selectmenu( "menuWidget" ).addClass( "overflow" ).perfectScrollbar();
});
```

CSS

```
#number{
    width: 220px;
}
.overflow{
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is : 
As I understood the element which we apply perfect-scrollbar to it should have an explicit height (100% or 400px or whatever) and that's ok I already added a class overflow which add the height to the list

```
$( "#number" ).selectmenu().selectmenu( "menuWidget" ).addClass( "overflow" )
```

then I applied the `perfectScrollbar()` function to that list **but it's still hidden and that is the problem**

jQuery is not able to calculate the height of an element if it's **hidden** (even if it has a **height** css property set)

So after looking at **jQuery ui selectmenu documentation** I was able to find an [open](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#event-open) event which we can use to do something when the list is opened

```
$( "#number" ).selectmenu({
    open: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#number" ).selectmenu( "menuWidget" ).addClass( "overflow" ).perfectScrollbar();
    }
})
```

What the code does is simple, it apply the `perfectScroll()` method only after the list is opened and jQuery is able to read the height

I hope this help someone in the same situation.